# Does ansible have a module that supports npm start?

Tags: node.js, npm, ansible, ansible-2.x

Does ansible have a module that supports npm start?

I've looked at the [npm module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/npm_module.html) but its main purpose seems to be the installation of npm packages. Fair enough. But how do I npm start? Do I need to fallback to using the [command module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html)?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do? Run your npm app in a continuous way? Then write a service file and treat is as a service with the *service* module.
If you want to run ist just as a single command, use the *command* module.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such thing in Ansible modules repo.

If I were you, I'd install supervisor (there are [package manager](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_packaging_modules.html#os) modules and [supervisorctl](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/supervisorctl_module.html) module for this task) and setup it to run your service.